# Using the Banach-Alaoglu Theorem to show that if $X$ is reflexive then $B_X$ is weakly compact.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, proof-verification, banach-spaces, compactness

> **Banach-Alaoglu Theorem:** 
>   Let $(X,||\cdot||)$ be a normed linear space. Then $B_{X^*}$ is weak$^*$ compact in $X$.

I want to show using the Banach-Alaoglu Theorem that,

> Let $(X,||\cdot||)$ be a reflexive normed linear space. Then $B_X$ is weakly compact.

My proof is presented below, but my lecturer has mentioned that the proof is not correct and he would like me to spot my mistake. But so far I don't understand why my proof is not correct. Am I missing something with regards to my understanding of the Theorem? My guess is that it's because I applied the theorem in $X^{**}$ instead of $X^*$. Is this a problem?

Before we state the proof, here is a note on notation:

> Let $(X\||\cdot||)$ be a normed linear space. We define the weak$^*$ topology on $X^*$ to be the topology generated by the subbasis
>   $\{\widehat{x}^{-1}(U)\in\mathcal{P}(X^*) : U \text{ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ and }\widehat{x}\in \widehat{X}\}$

where $\widehat{X}:=\{\widehat{x}:x\in X\}$ is the natural embedding of $X$ into $X^{**}$.

> My proof:
>   Since $\widehat{X}=X^{**}$ implies that $B_{\widehat{X}}=B_{X^{**}}$, it suffices to show that the natural embedding mapping $\phi : (X, \text{weak}) \to (\widehat{X}, \text{weak$^*$})$ is a homeomorphism. To this end, let $f^*\in X^*$ and $U$ open in $\mathbb{R}$. If $a\in X$ then
>   \begin{align*}
> \widehat{a} \in \phi({f^*}^{-1}(U))
> & \Leftrightarrow a\in {f^*}^{-1}(U) \\
> & \Leftrightarrow U \ni f^*(a) =\widehat{a}(f^*) = \widehat{f^*}(\widehat{a}) \\
> & \Leftrightarrow \widehat{a}\in \widehat{f^*}^{-1}(U)
> \end{align*}
>   Therefore $\phi({f^*}^{-1}(U)) = \widehat{f^*}^{-1}(U)$. Conversely, if $a\in X$ then 
>   \begin{align*}
> a\in\phi^{-1}(\widehat{f^*}^{-1}(U))
> &\Leftrightarrow \widehat{f^*}(\phi(a)) = \widehat{f^*}(\widehat{a}) = \widehat{a}(f^*) = f^*(a) \in U \\
> &\Leftrightarrow a\in {f^*}^{-1}(U)
> \end{align*} 
>   Thus, $\phi^{-1}(\widehat{f^*}^{-1}(U))={f^*}^{-1}(U)$ and indeed $\phi$ is a homeomorphism. Since $\phi$ is a bijection, then $\phi^{-1}(B_{\widehat{X}}) = B_X$. Since $B_{\widehat{X}}$ is compact by applying the Banach-Alaoglu Theorem, and because the image of a compact set is compact under a continuous function, we see that $B_X$ is compact in $X$ with the weak topology.

Comment: What you want to do is use that $X = X^{**} = (X^*)^*$.  Now the weak* topology $X^{**}$ is the topology that makes the linear functionals of its "predual" $X^*$ continuous functions on $X^{**}$. The weak topology on $X$ is the topology that makes the dual $X^*$ act continuously on $X$. Since the identification $X= X^{**}$ respects the action of $X^*$ these two topologies are the same.

Comment: For me it seems correct, you showed that the canonical embedding maps subbasis elements to subbasis elements and vice versa, from which it follows that you have an isomorphism.

Comment: So what did your lecturer say? Was he wrong?

Comment: He eventually said that it was not wrong, but it was just long-winded. Actually, I don't think I needed to show that the mapping $\phi$ is a homeomorphism since the natural embedding mapping is already an isometric isomorphism from $X$ to $\widehat{X}$. One just needs to know that since $X$ is reflexive, the weak and weak$^*$ topology coincide on $\widehat{X}$. Thus $B_{X^{**}}=B_{\widehat{X}}$ weakly compact, and hence $B_X$ is weakly compact.