# Giving a proof to the weak compactness of the unity ball in a reflexive normed space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, reflexive-space

So, I am trying to prove that if $X$ is a normed and reflexive space, its unity ball, that is $B$=$\lbrace x\in X : \parallel x\parallel =1\rbrace$, is weakly compact.

For that matter, I have already proven that:

1. $J:X \longrightarrow X''$ the natural embedding is continuous provided that $X$ has the $\tau_{d}$ topology (that is, the initial topology of $X'$) and $X''$ with $\tau_{d}^{''}*$
2. If $X$ is reflexive, $J$ is an homeomorphism (with respect the previous topologies).

My idea is to use Alaoglu-Bourbaki's theorem,which stablishes that the unity ball in $X'$ is weakly* compact, and use that the image of a compact is a compact through a continuous function.

Therefore, my problem is: if $B$=$\lbrace x\in X : \parallel x\parallel =1\rbrace$ is a subset of $X'$, how do I relate it? I mean, I just do not know how to finish the argument, which I feel to be very close to me.

Also, I have checked [Using the Banach-Alaoglu Theorem to show that if $X$ is reflexive then $B_X$ is weakly compact.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2301080/using-the-banach-alaoglu-theorem-to-show-that-if-x-is-reflexive-then-b-x-is)  but I think it uses the algebraic dual, or I just don't fully understand his proof.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a theorem of Kakutani, proved in the answer. I have not seen a proof that does not use dual spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rather detailed proof.

If $X$ is reflexive, the natural embedding $J:X\to X''$
is an isometric isomorphism. In particular, the weak topology on $X$, that is, the topology $\sigma(X,X')$, is identical to the weak topology on $X''$, that is, the topology $\sigma(X'',X''')$. Let $B_X$ denote the unit ball of $X$. Then $J(B_X)$ is the unit ball of $X''$. By Alaoglu's theorem (Bourbaki had nothing to do with it), the unit ball of $X''$ is compact in the $\sigma(X'',I(X'))$ topology, where $I$ is the natural embedding of $X'$ into $X'''$. But $I:X'\to X'''$ is an injective isometry, so if a set is compact in the $\sigma(X'',I(X'))$ topology then clearly it is also compact in the larger topology $\sigma(X'',X''')$. Therefore, the unit ball of $X''$ is compact in the $\sigma(X'',X''')$ topology, and therefore its inverse image under the homomorphism $J$, namely, $B_X$,  is compact in the weak topology of $X$.

Comment: I am sorry for asking this, but I'm definitely not proficient in topology or functional analysis: why is the weak topology on $X$ identical to the weak topology on $X''$ provided J is an homeomorphism? Also, where do you use the weak* topology? That last thing might be a notation issue.